# Help with gaussian elimination of a very simple equation system.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently working on the following problem:

Let $A =\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\c & d\\\end{bmatrix}$ and let $ X = \begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\\ \end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix} e\\ f\\ \end{bmatrix}$.

Let $ad-bc \neq0$ and solve with Gauss-Jordan elimination the equation system $AX = B$. Show that there is a unique solution.

First I write this as:
$\begin{cases} ax + by = e,\\cx + dy = f.\\\end{cases}$

According to the textbook the solution should be: $x = \frac{bf-de}{ad-bc}$ and $y = \frac{af-ce}{ad-bc}$.

How do they get there using Gauss-Jordan? Is there something here that I have missed? Thank you kindly for your help!

Comment: There shouldn't be plus signs in your matrix.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have the plus signs in $A$- it is a $2 \times 2$ matrix.  To do Gauss-Jordan on the system you write $$\begin{bmatrix} a & b & e\\c & d & f\\\end{bmatrix}\to\begin{bmatrix} a & b & e\\\frac cd & 1 & \frac fd\\\end{bmatrix}\to \begin{bmatrix} a-\frac {bc}d & 0 & e-\frac{bf}d\\\frac cd & 1 & \frac fd\\\end{bmatrix}\to \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & (e-\frac{bf}d)\frac d{ad-bc}\\\frac cd & 1 & \frac fd\\\end{bmatrix}$$ and so on.  Now subtract $\frac cd$ times the first row from the second and simplify.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That was a bit more complicated than I thought it would be... It was the first question after reading this chapter in my textbook.